# Overusing code behind in my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, design-patterns

I'm creating a simple WPF application for practice purposes only, but I have little experience in WPF. Using  WPF XAML seems troublesome to me, as I have a lot more experience with C# Console and especially with the C#- and JS-driven videogame engine Unity, where devs have access to an Editor (analogous to the Design Window in WPF) and the code behind, with no XAML whatsoever. This is why I tend to use less XAML and much code behind.

For example here, I modify the Margin property of a button, while I set its Opacity to 1; this all happens upon a click event to the grid, which calls the function (exactly the way it's done in Unity):

```
public  void Grid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            RandomButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            RandomButton.Opacity = 1;

        }
```

If I'm not mistaken, this can be achieved through Data Binding in XAML as well, although it seems to be a lot more complicated method seemingly producing the same result.

So my questions are: is there a difference between the two ways, say, performance-wise or in terms of expandability (which one would be easier to expand/modify later)? Which one is used in the industry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference as far as the performance is concerned. For any element that you define in your XAML markup, an instance of a corresponding type will be created by the framework at runtime.

It is generally much easier to define the visual presentation of an application using XAML though. This is what XAML is used for after all: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295302.aspx

You still use a programming language such as C# to implement your application logic though, i.e. what happens when a mouse button is pressed etc. So setting/modifying the properties of any element that you originally create in the XAML markup using C# is fine.

> Which one is used in the industry?

When it comes to enterprise WPF applications *the* recommended design pattern to use is MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel). You can refer to the following link for more information about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

The view is responsible for defining the structure, layout, and appearance of what the user sees on the screen and is typically created using only XAML whereas the view model and the model that are responsible for handling the view logic and business logic respectively is implemented using a programming language like C#.

You will find a lot more information and samples of how to implement the MVVM design pattern if you Google or Bing for it.

Comment: Thank you! If I get your answer right, then, I should separate my code into at least 3 distinct, but connected pieces: one for design in XAML (the view), one for the "heavy lifting" such as calculations etc.  in C# or any other language (the business logic)  and one to connect them (the view logic). One more related question though : Is there a rule of thumb to decide the appropriate "section" for the parts of my code?

Comment: That's right. It is the nature of the code and what kind of logic it defines that decides whether it belongs to the view, view model or model. Please refer to the link I supplied for more information. You may also want to read this: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234251/what-really-is-the-business-logic

Answer (score 1):

Hi being a WPF/XAML developer I would suggest you to use XAML as much as you can.Make use of commands and bindings i.e use MVVM architecture. What if you want to set the opacity using keys (example: ctrl+shift) you will have to write another code behind for that making your code redundant affecting performance of your app. Make use of MVVM pattern ( You can use MVVM light by galasoft). As of expanding or modification you will have to modify a single command method rather than modifying each event etc on the code behind. Easy to test ..Easy to build..Easy to modify..

Comment: Thank you! I will look up MVVM.